# Setting up TOR on a router

Tags: tor, router

I've asked a much more complicated version of this question a week ago with many views but no responses, so I'm going to simplify the question here.

I understand that there is a TOR **browser** that can be downloaded which you can run on your computer to hide your presence on the internet. My understanding is that it is meant to work as your browser only, and if you do other things on the internet, like remote desktop or ssh or scp, that those things are not protected by your TOR browser. Is this correct?

My goal is to route ALL actives form all my computers i.e. any TCP/IP or UDP packets, DNS queries, etc.  to or from any applications by setting up a TOR **router**. Am I being naive, or is there really such a thing? If there is, then it doesn't sound like the "TOR Browser" that I want because my applications go beyond internet browsing.

What I am imagining is that I take my home-made, self-configured Ubuntu router, which is already set up to provide DNS, NAT, and DHCP to all my computers, and install "***something to do with TOR***" that transforms it into a router that takes any and ALL traffic from all my machines and wraps it up in a TOR onion before sending it on its way across the internet. Is this just a figment of my imagination, or does this capability really exist?

Finally, if what I want to do can actually be done, where do I get the software to do it? All I can find is the "TOR **Browser**" which as I explained above, just doesn't sound like what I'm looking for. Is there a separate TOR package somewhere for installing on a router?

I hope someone can help.

-gt-

Comment: Tor is a browser not some kind of VPN.

Comment: @David That is why in my final paragraph I said I didn't believe I wanted "TOR Browser", and was asking whether or not there was some other TOR software that acts like a VPN.  Is the answer "No, TOR is only a browser"? The reason I am unclear on this issue is I've seen a video on youtube where a Raspberry Pi is used as a wireless access point connected by Ethernet to the ISP and uses TOR. Is it just acting as a proxy for port 80 stuff from the connected computers? The video claimed that DNS entries were also "TORed" so it seemed more than just port 80 ...

Comment: [Whonix Gateway](https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Whonix-Gateway) is exactly the software you are looking for.

Comment: @09676877 thats like tails. It is an OS for the end user. I think the author is asking for a device that acts as router only to serve the onion sevice to all clients. Like he mentioned, a rpi where clients log in via wifi and are only able to use tor without exception.

Comment: That's a pretty old post now - you're right, AlexOnLinux. You've described what I was looking for. In the meantime, I've since went with a VPN provider. Interestingly, they have an option for TOR, but I've never used that option. So obviously, there's some way to do this. I would have liked to have figured it out and set up my own solution, but I now have 36 servers behind my home-built router which tunnels through my VPN service, and I can't halt production to fuss with this now. At least the VPN is VERY cheap, given that I only have one device (my router) using the service.